# Which checkboxes are selected in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, checkbox, matlab-guide

When I want to know which radio buttons are selected in a panel in a MATLAB GUI, I use this line:

```
ChosenOption = get(handles.OptionPanel, 'SelectedObject');
```

where `OptionPanel` is the Tag of the panel where the radio buttons are located.

However, if I want to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons, is there any way to do the same?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is `SelectedObject`? Shouldn't there be a property name, like `Value`  or something else?

Comment: @Divakar `SelectedObject` is a property of a `uibuttongroup`, giving a handle to the currently selected radiobutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically get the `Value` property of each checkbox to determine whether it was checked or not.

Note that typically with checkboxes any, all, or none of the checkboxes may be selected (in contrast to radio buttons, where typically only a single radio button would be selected at any one time), so you would want to get the `Value` property of each checkbox separately. There's no equivalent of a `uibuttongroup` that you would use with radio buttons (although you can of course graphically group the checkboxes in a `uipanel`).